# How to draw borders that criss-cross in the corner of div

Tags: css

I there a way to make each border in a div extend 1 or 2 pixels in each way so that they form a cross in each corner?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it by default css `border` property. However, you can achieve what you want by trying `:before` and `:after` selectors for the div:

```
<div class="cross-borders"></div>

.cross-borders {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-top:0;
    border-bottom:0;
    position:relative;
    margin:20px auto;
}
.cross-borders:before,
.cross-borders:after {
    content: ' ';
    width:210px;
    height:1px;
    background-color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:-5px;
}
.cross-borders:after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qgmx9ot/)

Comment: that was awesome!